# Why one logical core in my processor is idle

Tags: intel-core-i7, hyper-threading, idle, logical-processor

I have an Intel Core i7 4790 processor which has 4 cores 8 threads.

When I run games or programs, only 7 of the logical cores are activated and one stays at zero or 2-3% usage.

What is happening here? And how can I activate all the 8 logical cores?

Comment: Are you actually having a problem or just asking because...? The OS and running software are perfectly capable of managing resources. If resources aren't needed resources aren't used or "activated", end of story.

Comment: I want to know if there is any issue or is it normal. No matter how many programs and games I open simultaneously. That one logical core is not being utilized. Where as other cores are reaching 90%. Why is that logical core left out. I think there is a issue

Comment: It's a problem of perception.

Answer (score 2):

### This is normal.

Any program creates the number of threads it needs. Usually there are from one to eight. The OS allocates processor cores to these threads. The game has 7 threads, so 7 CPU cores are occupied.

One core can contain multiple program threads. One thread cannot exist in two cores. Therefore, if the core power is not enough, you cannot split the thread into two cores. It can *only* be transferred to another core. Even if you have 20 cores, the program will still use as many as it is programmed to do.

If a program has 8 or more threads, all cores will be running. You can also run several games that load 7 cores. If one instance of the game loads all 7 cores by 25%. Then by launching the second copy, the load will increase to 50%. When the fifth instance is launched, the eighth core will start working.

But if there is a weak point in the computer, for example a video card. The CPU will not work at 100% if it is slowed down by the video card.